# Ios Pro Features Include Push grayed, but ticked

Tags: codenameone

I am Pro subscription on codenameone, I just found in my project setting page, at the IOS Pro Features is grayed and does not allow me to "untick" the "Include Push", it is ticked automatically.

This make me get the compilation error, saying that I need to either generate an ios certificate with Push Enable, or untick the "Include Push". In fact I do not need the Push function in my apps.

How to untick that checkbox to avoid the compilation error message?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest logging in again in the Codename One Settings to refresh the account status as the settings UI doesn't re-check the pro status. This should remove the gray overlay.

Notice that the user level pro should be listed next to your account within that UI.

Comment: Yes, after re-login again, problem solved... thank you!!